# Email body did not displaying in html

Tags: php, email, html-email, imap

I'm working on my code to fetch and read my emails using php. I have got a problem with reading my email when I sent myself an test email. I am unable to read the email into text/html when I tried this:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$imap = imap_open("{imap.mydomain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "rob@mydomain.com", "mypassword") or die("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error());


$message = imap_fetchbody($imap,217, 1);


$message = nl2br($message);

echo $message;


/* close the connection */

imap_close($imap);


?>
```

I have also tried this:

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($imap,217, 1.2);
```

When I tried `imap_fetchbody($imap,217, 1.2);`, it will not display the email in text/html, so when I tried `imap_fetchbody($imap,217, 1)`, it will only display the email body as plain/text. I want to read my email in text/html but i have got no idea how to do this.

I have checked in the header and it show: `Content-Type: multipart/alternative;`

I'm using pear mail imap library to read my emails.

Can you please show me an example how I could be able to read my email in text/html so I could be able to see the hyperlink and html code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation for the `imap_fetchbody` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php), the section argument is

> a string of integers delimited by period which index into a body part list as per the IMAP4 specification

so try passing it as a string instead of as a floating point number:

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($imap,217, "1.2");
```